# Reusing style attributes in xml files

Tags: android

I have a few `textviews` defined in a `ConstraintLayout`. Each of them has different attributes but there are some overlaps like:

```
<TextView
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
    />
```

Is there any way of "reusing" these attributes similar to an `include` tag so that I do not need to repeat these across all the views?

Comment: create custom style with the attributes and apply in your textview

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom style for `TextView` and use it in your layout file.

In `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <!--More custom overlapping Style Attributes -->
</style>
```

And in Layout file

```
<TextView
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
/>
```

This Way you can reuse the attributes.